# Java class using ArrayList as attribute

Tags: java, android, exception, arraylist

I am implementing a very simple class that allows me to simply perform get/post/put/delete requests on a RestfullAPI.

```
public class NetCampusRequest {
    private String url;
    private List payload;

    public NetCampusRequest(String startUri) {
        url = startUri;
        payload = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public List<NameValuePair> getPayload() {
        return payload;
    }

    public void addParameter(String key, String value) {
        payload.add(new BasicNameValuePair(key, value));
    }

    public void getRequest() {
        for (int i=0; i < payload.size(); i++)
            url += "?" + payload.get(i);
        System.out.println(url);
        //HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        //HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet()
    }
}
```

I am far from being good in object oriented language, but it seems that the error comes from the addParameter method.

Also, it says that there is a NullPointerException and the app is working perfectly fine but I don't think that so much warnings are "fine".

```
07-03 14:20:49.760  19869-19869/fr.netcampus E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: fr.netcampus, PID: 19869
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{fr.netcampus/fr.netcampus.DisplaySchoolsActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
        at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
        at fr.netcampus.DisplaySchoolsActivity.onCreate(DisplaySchoolsActivity.java:57)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is the problem? Please post the logcat or something so we can help.

Comment: private `List` payload; should be `List<NameValuePair>`

Comment: Try to stick to the Java coding conventions, more specifically accolades not on a new line, especially since it makes code blocks on StackOverflow much more readable.

Comment: `private List<NameValuePair> payload;`; the rest looks okay, what happens on `new BasicNameValuePair(key, value)` when `key` or `name` is null? The stacktrace shows the method and line number.

Comment: Sorry I was not sure about dumping the whole logcat but I update it.

Comment: According to your log, none of the problems are in your NetCampusRequest class.
I don't think that is the exception you were looking for (is not a NullPointerException) but if, as you say, you have an exception in addParameter, you should probably check the constructor of BasicNameValuePair

Comment: The text of your Question and the logcat output are CONTRADICTORY.  If you are going to give us dodgy evidence, there's not much we can do to help you.  (Even if you are dressed as a purple wizard ... :-) )